# Javascript Function back to it's original place

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm not actually a programmer but I have to do this website work properly. And for that I'll need your help.

I'm messing with some javascript and I manage to maek this:

```
<script>

    function funcaosabores1() {
        document.getElementById("testeagora1").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById('contento1').style.visibility="visible";
        document.getElementById('contento2').style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById('contento3').style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById('contento4').style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById('contento5').style.visibility="hidden";
}

    function funcaosabores2() {
        document.getElementById("testeagora2").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById('contento2').style.visibility="visible";
        document.getElementById('contento1').style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById('contento3').style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById('contento4').style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById('contento5').style.visibility="hidden";
}

    function funcaosabores3() {
        document.getElementById("testeagora3").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById('contento3').style.visibility="visible";
        document.getElementById('contento1').style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById('contento2').style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById('contento4').style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById('contento5').style.visibility="hidden";
}

    function funcaosabores4() {
        document.getElementById("testeagora4").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById('contento4').style.visibility="visible";
        document.getElementById('contento1').style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById('contento2').style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById('contento3').style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById('contento5').style.visibility="hidden";
}

    function funcaosabores5() {

        document.getElementById("testeagora5").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById('contento5').style.visibility="visible";
        document.getElementById('contento1').style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById('contento2').style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById('contento3').style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById('contento4').style.visibility="hidden";
}
</script>
```

And I can't find on how to make for example: funcaosabores1 is clicked and is now visible, when I click funcaosabores2, the first one is hidden and the second is showing. But I can't click on the first one back because it was already clicked. (Idk if it's called return)

This is the div's called in the script:

```
    <div class="animacao_saborgingerale" id="contento2" style="visibility:hidden;"></div>
<div class="animacao_saboruvasyrah" id="contento3" style="visibility:hidden;"></div>
<div class="animacao_sabortangerina" id="contento4" style="visibility:hidden;"></div>
<div class="animacao_saboruvabranca" id="contento5" style="visibility:hidden;"></div>


    <div class="sabor-melancia"><p onclick="funcaosabores1()" id="testeagora1">MELANCIA</p> </div>
<div class="sabor-gingerale"><p onclick="funcaosabores2()" id="testeagora2">GINGER ALE</p></div>
<div class="sabor-uvasyrah"><p onclick="funcaosabores3()" id="testeagora3">UVA SYRAH</p></div>
<div class="sabor-tangerina"><p onclick="funcaosabores4()" id="testeagora4">TANGERINA</p></div>
<div class="sabor-uvabranca"><p onclick="funcaosabores5()" id="testeagora5">UVA BRANCA</p></div>
```

This seems quite messy but I'm here if you guys can help me! Thanks.

The CodePen of how it is right now. @nielsdebruin

Comment: This is insanely, extravagantly, humongously verbose. This can be cut down to a quarter of the size.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you want this code to do. Are you looking for a toggle?

Comment: @TrevorD I think yes, not sure with the termology but I've been looking all day on the internet and can't actually find it.

Comment: Please create a CodePen or JSFiddle so we can see your code in action. That way it's easier for us to understand your question and we can better assist you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just want to do something like this:

```js
let prevButton;
let prevContent;
function toggle(e) {
    if (prevButton) prevButton.style.visibility = 'visible';
    prevButton = e.target;
    e.target.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    let id = e.target.id;
    let number = id.slice(-1);
    if (prevContent) prevContent.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    prevContent = document.getElementById('contento' + number);
    prevContent.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

```html
<div class="content animacao_saborgingerale" id="contento1" style="visibility:hidden;">1</div>
<div class="content animacao_saborgingerale" id="contento2" style="visibility:hidden;">2</div>
<div class="content animacao_saboruvasyrah" id="contento3" style="visibility:hidden;">3</div>
<div class="content animacao_sabortangerina" id="contento4" style="visibility:hidden;">4</div>
<div class="content animacao_saboruvabranca" id="contento5" style="visibility:hidden;">5</div>


<div class="button sabor-melancia"><p onclick="toggle(event)" id="testeagora1">MELANCIA</p> </div>
<div class="button sabor-gingerale"><p onclick="toggle(event)" id="testeagora2">GINGER ALE</p></div>
<div class="button sabor-uvasyrah"><p onclick="toggle(event)" id="testeagora3">UVA SYRAH</p></div>
<div class="button sabor-tangerina"><p onclick="toggle(event)" id="testeagora4">TANGERINA</p></div>
<div class="button sabor-uvabranca"><p onclick="toggle(event)" id="testeagora5">UVA BRANCA</p></div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Thanks dave!
I didn't even know it had a command called "let". Thank you very much!

Comment: let is an es6 command.  That might break if you have to support Internet explorer 10 or older.  Swap `let` for `var` if you need older browser support.